# CSharp - Treeview ImageKey didnt work

Tags: c#, treeview, treeviewitem

if I **click on a node and it is a file, the image automatically changes to the folder image.**
You can see this in the picture.

[image]
There is no MouseClick-Event - even a MouseDoubleClick-Event.

Code-Snippets:

**Add the Icons to the ImageList:**

```
private void LoadImageList()
{
     imageList = new ImageList();
     imageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16);
     imageList.Images.Add("folder", new System.Drawing.Icon(Application.StartupPath + "\\res\\" + "folder2.ico"));
     imageList.Images.Add("file", new System.Drawing.Icon(Application.StartupPath + "\\res\\" + "file2.ico"));
     tVDirectories.ImageList = imageList;
}
```

**Update the TreeView:**

```
private void UpdateTreeView(string pFtpPath, TreeNode pCurrentTreeNode)
{
     [...]
     TreeNode hostNode = tVDirectories.Nodes.Find("ftpServer", false)[0];
     hostNode.Text = _ftpServerFullPath;

     TreeNode childNode;
     List<string> ftpDirectories = GetFtpCurrentDirectoryList(pFtpPath);
     foreach (string item in ftpDirectories)
     {
          childNode = new TreeNode(item);
          childNode.Name = item;
          if (item.Contains('.'))
          {
               childNode.ImageIndex = 1; //.ImageKey = "file";
          }
          else
          {
               childNode.ImageIndex = 0; //.ImageKey = "folder";
          }
          hostNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the following:

@kamino said there is a good example and there I found the following:
`myTreeView.SelectedImageIndex = 0;`

And that's it:

```
childNode.ImageIndex = 1; // ImageKey = "file";
childNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem comes from the fact that the `ImageKey` sets the image only when your node is not selected. You should use `ImageIndex` instead: a good example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.imageindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Quoting MSDN [related page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The key of the default image shown for each node TreeView control when
>   the node is in an unselected state.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is still the same. (Question edited)